# relation one to many in asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, one-to-many

I'm new in asp.net and this is my first project . i have two table student and notes . student has many notes so  i want to display list of student with their list of notes but i got this error in postmen There was an error parsing JSON data Unexpected end of JSON input. and in console Self referencing loop detected for property 'student' with type 'firstExp.Models.Student'. Path '[0].notes[0]'.

this is student model

```
public class Student
    {
         public int StudentId { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
          public ICollection<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
               = new List<Notes>();
    }
```

this is notes model

```
 public class Notes {
        public int NotesId { get; set; }
         [Required]
        public string NoteValue { get; set; }
         [Required]

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey ("StudentId")]
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is student controller

```
namespace firstExp.Controllers
{
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private StudentContext _studentContext;

        public StudentController(StudentContext context)
        {
            _studentContext = context;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>> Get()
        {
            return _studentContext.Students.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName).Include(c => c.Notes).ToList();
        }

}

}
```

```
this is OnModelCreating  method

  protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder) {
            base.OnModelCreating (builder);

            builder.Entity<Student> ().ToTable ("Students");
            builder.Entity<Student> ().HasKey (p => p.StudentId);
            builder.Entity<Student> ().Property (p => p.StudentId).IsRequired ().ValueGeneratedOnAdd ();
            builder.Entity<Student> ().Property (p => p.FirstName).IsRequired ().HasMaxLength (30);
            builder.Entity<Student> ().HasMany (p => p.Notes).WithOne (p => p.Student).HasForeignKey (p => p.StudentId);

            builder.Entity<Notes> ().ToTable ("Notes");
            builder.Entity<Notes> ().HasKey (p => p.NotesId);
            builder.Entity<Notes>().Property(p => p.NotesId).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
              builder.Entity<Notes>().Property(p => p.NoteValue).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
             builder.Entity<Notes>().Property(p => p.Subject).IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

what i'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Could u please your OnModelCreating()?

Comment: i dont have this method in my project . :/

Comment: You should follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-database-context-1) to create the tables and, also, don't forget to override to override the DbContext.OnModelCreating(). In that method you shall write your [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: thank you for you answer . i did follow that article and worked fine  but it use in memory database and i want to use sql server  so i used migration to create my database and it contains all table with correct relations so i didn't think there is a problem in relationship  but now i will override the DbContext.OnModelCreating()

Comment: Yes, you need to apply migrations in case you don't use an inmemorydb. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `Json.NET` to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph. This is done in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );

    ...
}
```

Refer to [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

Your Notes class:

```
 public class Notes {
    public int NotesId { get; set; }
     [Required]
    public string NoteValue { get; set; }
     [Required]

    public string Subject { get; set; }


    public Student Student { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey ("Student")]        
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

In your `SchollContext` class, override the DbContext.OnModelCreating() and in there you shall define the relationships you want. Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) to see how you can do that.
In your SchoolContext class declare the DbSets:

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
```

And your OnModelCreating() should look like this one:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Notes>().HasOne<Student>(n => n.Student)
            .WithMany(s => s.Notes)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Notes>().ToTable("Notes");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Now, delete all of your migrations and delete the tables or the db, and apply the migrations again.
Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer, i edited my question and i ovveride the DbContext.OnModelCreating() but i still got the same error

Comment: thank you but the solution is to add  .AddJsonOptions :)